# How to convert expression with Subscript to string

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting, conversion, boxes

I've tried `ToString[]`, but it doesn't work properly with subscripts:

[image]

How to convert `expr` containing subscript to a string with exactly the same `FullForm` that `"expr"` has?

---

### UPDATE by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd)

There actually exists a more general issue behind the specific problem above, that is, how to convert an expression containing 2D format into corresponding string that retains the format programmatically? For example, how to convert

```
{a^b + 1, 1.23*10^2, 2 Subscript[a, b]}
(* Please Press Ctrl+Shift+N to convert it to standard form *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

to

```
{"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)+1", "1.23\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(2\
\)]\)", "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The attempt is easy to achieve by hand: we just need to place quotes around the expression and place a `\[Times]` between `1.23` and `10^2`, but how to do this with program? `ToString` won't work, as shown above.

Comment: How did you originally get the left-hand side of Equal in In[164]?

Comment: Presumably output of `Subscript[t, 1]` copied & pasted into quotes.

Comment: \quote, t, Ctrl+-, \quote

Comment: @Stepan Which *Mathematica* version do you use? I get `"\!\(t\_1\)"` only with version 5.2, but both with versions 8.0.4 and 11.0.0 I get `"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(1\)]\)"` (Win7 x64).

Comment: @xzczd `ToString` always creates the same string from identical expressions but there is no simple way to convert `"\!\(t\_1\)"` to `"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(1\)]\)"` or backward. Moreover, there are many ways to display visually the same using different code, for example `ToString["\!\(t\_1\)", StandardForm] // FullForm` returns entirely different string which is rendered identical to `"\!\(t\_1\)"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to convert a expression containing 2D format into corresponding
>   string that retains the format programmatically? For example, how to
>   convert
>
> ```
> {a^b + 1, 1.23*10^2, 2 Subscript[a, b]}
> (* Please Press Ctrl+Shift+N to convert it to standard form *)
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> to
>
> ```
> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)+1", "1.23\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(2\
> \)]\)", "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)"}
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The easiest way is to prevent evaluation of the expressions what can be done with `Unevaluated` and `HoldAll`. First, define the function

```
toString = Function[expr, ToString[Unevaluated@expr, StandardForm], HoldAll];
```

Now you can simply apply this function to an expression:

[image: screenshot]

You can `Map` it over the list for obtaining separate string for every expression in the list:

[image: screenshot]

Or you can make this function `Listable` and it will thread over the lists automatically:

```
toString = Function[expr, ToString[Unevaluated@expr, StandardForm], {HoldAll, Listable}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh… seems that I'm still not familiar enough with evaluation control, I simply forgot about its possibility and get bogged down in the mud of low level notebook structure! +1 of course.

Comment: Is there a way to add a mathematical expression to the subscript, and then convert everything to a string? For example, let's say I want to convert `Subscript["p", 2 + 3]` to a string (in Mathematica, this would look like $p_{2+3}$) and concatenate it with the string `"Test"`. Using your formula, I tried `ToString2[Subscript["p", 2 + 3]] <> "Test"` but it yields $p_{2 + 3} \text{Test}$ instead of $p_5 \text{Test}$. Any idea?

Comment: @alejnavab `toString[Evaluate@Subscript["p", 2 + 3]] <> "Test"`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks! One last question, related to my previous one. I want to add a string in the subscript as well as a mathematical expression. Using my previous example, I'd like to get $p_{\text{Hi} 5}$ (the string is "Hi", the mathematical expression is "2+3"). I tried using `ToString2[Subscript["p", "Hi" 2 + 3]]` but it yields $p_{3+2\text{Hi}}$ instead of $p_{\text{Hi} 5}$. How can this be done? I can't directly use `ToString2[Subscript["p", "Hi5"]]` because I want to use a formula in the subscript.

Comment: @alejnavab `toString[Evaluate@Subscript["p", Row[{"Hi" , 2 + 3}]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

Obtaining the box form from `FullForm[ToBoxes["t1"]]` (that's t subscript 1) - the box form can be used in a function like so:-

```
make[x_, n_] := 
 ToExpression[
  StringJoin["\"\\!\\(\\*SubscriptBox[\\(", ToString[x], "\\), \\(", 
   ToString[n], "\\)]\\)\""]]

make[t, 1]

make[t, 1] == "t1" (* again, t subscript 1 *)
```

> True

To convert a subscripted variable another function can be used:-

```
f[x_] := Module[{a, b},
  a = x[[1]];
  b = x[[2]];
  make[a, b]]

f[t1]
```

> "t1"

To convert an expression such as the following more manipulations will be needed.

```
expr = s + Subscript[t, 1] + u (* Hold can be used to preserve the order *)
```

> s + u + t1

The problem is a matter of manipulating the output from this ...

```
ToBoxes[expr]
```

> RowBox[{"s", "+", "u", "+", SubscriptBox["t", "1"]}]

... to the output here:

```
ToBoxes["s+u+t1"] (* expr with t subscript 1 pasted into quotes*)

(* "\"s+u+\\!\\(\\*SubscriptBox[\\(t\\), \\(1\\)]\\)\"" *)
```

For this example the manipulation can be done like so:

```
z = ToBoxes[expr];

ToExpression[
 StringJoin["\"",
  First[z] /. SubscriptBox[a_, b_] :>
    StringJoin["\\!\\(\\*SubscriptBox[\\(", a, "\\), \\(", b, "\\)]\\)"],
  "\""]]
```

> "s+u+t1"

The output here includes t subscript 1.